# Mysql update violates the composite key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I want to execute a simple update. Just to increase some amount to one column but I have issues with the composite key.

```
--given this table
CREATE TABLE `user_amounts` (   
      `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
      `amount` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,   
      `user_id` bigint NOT NULL,   
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
       UNIQUE KEY `UK25hzjmhhedgmgy936lfanet49` (`user_id`,`amount`) 
);

--given those values
insert into user_amounts values (1, 0.03, 1), (2, 0.05, 1);

--when I try to increase amounts I cannot because of the unique constraint
update user_amounts set amount = amount + 0.02;
```

I know I can remove the constraint to execute this. But I wonder if there is any other way of doing this since eventually after the update the conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: That's true, the second row has user_id/amount  which is the same as that which would be updated to for the first row - if you are you trying to update all rows drop the constraint before the update then add it back after.

Comment: if I remove the constraint then how I'm going to be protected if someone else insert a duplicated amount? I could wrap everything inside a SERIALIZABLE transaction, do some select for insert of everything and remove constraint. But.... all this to do a simple update? I just wonder if is there any easier path

Answer (score 1):

Try this - 'If an UPDATE statement includes an ORDER BY clause, the rows are updated in the order specified by the clause'

```
CREATE TABLE `user_amounts` (   
      `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
      `amount` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,   
      `user_id` bigint NOT NULL,   
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
       UNIQUE KEY key1(`user_id`,`amount`) 
);

insert into user_amounts values (1, 0.03, 1), (2, 0.05, 1);

select * from user_amounts;

update user_amounts set amount = amount + 0.02
order by user_id,amount desc;

select * from user_amounts;

+----+--------+---------+
| id | amount | user_id |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |   0.05 |       1 |
|  2 |   0.07 |       1 |
+----+--------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

and read the para starting If an UPDATE statement includes an ORDER BY clause, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html -

Comment: It works for the example given. But let's say I don't know what's the amount to be received, it could be +2 (it works) or it could be -2. In reality what I have is some function: set amount = amount  / other_table.other_field (I'm using join) so the amount could be smaller or bigger for each row.

Comment: Not enough detail - You could put the update in a procedure and decide which way to order if the change is uniform for each user_id's rows, but if increment/decrement for each user_id's  rows is not uniform I really can't help. And drop index might not help because you might hit duplicates when you recreate index.

Comment: okay, sorry for the missing information.

Comment: Let me add some info. Each user is having currency. Let's say user 1 is having EUR and user 2 is having GBP. I'm updating the amounts based on exchange rate fluctuations. So, all amounts for user 1 could go up, and all amounts for user 2 could go down.
To simplify let's say you have these values:
insert into user_amounts values (1, 0.03, 1), (2, 0.05, 1);
insert into user_amounts values (3, 0.06, 2), (4, 0.04, 2);
and we want as a final result these values:
insert into user_amounts values (1, 0.05, 1), (2, 0.07, 1);
insert into user_amounts values (3, 0.04, 2), (4, 0.02, 2);

Comment: Your table should know about the related currency..